# MSBuild deletes one lib file, breaking the build. Visual Studio works fine

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have project dependencies like this:

```
Main -> A, Common
A -> B, Common
```

with the build order:

```
Common
B
A
Main
```

The solution builds fine in Visual Studio 2019.  But in MSBuild, it builds `Common.lib`, `B.lib`, `A.lib` ... then deletes `Common.lib`, before trying (and failing) to build `Main.exe`.

I've tried changing the output dir of `Common.lib`, but every time MSBuild will build it in the new location, then delete it after `A.lib` is built.  It doesn't delete `A.lib` or `B.lib`, even when they're in the same dir as `Common.lib`. I also have another solution with a different Main project with the same dependencies (`A`, `B` and `Common`), but MSBuild works fine on that.

Any ideas where to start troubleshooting this?

All projects are in C++ with MFC in a static library, using multibyte character set (the solution was upgraded from VC2005). I'm running MSBuild from command line (cmd.exe).  Version numbers:

```
Visual Studio 16.8.5 
MSBuild 16.8.3.61104
```

---

Update:

The build log using `-verbosity:diag` as @dxiv suggested now gives this build hierarchy at the end. (I've renamed the projects to match the names above)

```
============================== Build Hierarchy (IDs represent configurations) =====================================================
Id                  : Exclusive Time   Total Time   Path (Targets)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                   : 0.429s           105.369s     D:\releases\temp_src\Main.sln (rebuild) 
. 1                 : 0.270s           104.941s     D:\releases\temp_src\Main.vcxproj.metaproj (Rebuild) 
| | 2               : 6.218s           31.257s      D:\releases\temp_src\A\A.vcxproj (Rebuild) 
| | | 3             : 1.600s           1.600s       D:\releases\temp_src\B\B.vcxproj (Clean) 
| | | 4             : 0.764s           0.764s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj (Clean) 
| | | 5             : 2.184s           2.184s       D:\releases\temp_src\B\B.vcxproj () 
| | | 6             : 2.507s           2.507s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj () 
| | | 7             : 0.536s           0.536s       D:\releases\temp_src\B\B.vcxproj (GetNativeManifest) 
| | | 8             : 0.643s           0.643s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj (GetNativeManifest) 
| | | 9             : 0.585s           0.585s       D:\releases\temp_src\B\B.vcxproj (GetProjectInfoForReference) 
| | | 10            : 0.668s           0.668s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj (GetProjectInfoForReference) 
| | . 11            : 0.549s           0.549s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems) 
| . 12              : 5.923s           10.062s      D:\releases\temp_src\Main.vcxproj (Rebuild) 
| | | 13            : 0.696s           0.696s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj (Clean) 
| | | 14            : 1.845s           1.845s       D:\releases\temp_src\A\A.vcxproj (GetNativeManifest) 
| | | 15            : 0.969s           0.969s       D:\releases\temp_src\A\A.vcxproj (GetProjectInfoForReference) 
| | . 16            : 0.629s           0.629s       D:\releases\temp_src\Common\Common.vcxproj (GetProjectInfoForReference)
```

ID 13 shows `Common.vcxproj` being cleaned just as `Main` begins the rebuild; this seems like the action that deleted the `Common.lib`.  What could cause it to perform this clean?

Comment: Try adding `-verbosity:diag` to the `msbuild` command line, maybe there is some clue there.

Comment: What did you mean by that? Delete common project's output file and also delete the other two A,B projects output files when you build Main project? Or is it a strange behavior you faced?

Comment: Change the OutDir property for common project and then when you execute the clean target, it did not delete the A and B's output files?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I mean it doesn't delete A.lib and B.lib in either case (whether I change Common's OutDir or not).  Those 2 libs are still there after the build fails, but Common.lib is deleted both times - even when all 3 project's OutDir is the same.

Comment: You meant that when the main project build failed, the A and B, Common's output files should be removed at the same time?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT no - Main failed because the linker can't find Common's lib file. Main depends on A and Common, so I'm expecting MSBuild to keep the two libs around until Main has been linked.  

I'm now looking though the build log with the `-verbosity:diag` switch as @dxiv suggested (it really is a lot more verbose); I'll update if I see something interesting.

Comment: @dxiv With `-verbosity:diag`, the log now shows that it cleans `Common` just as `Main` begins to rebuild - I've updated the question with the build hierarchy.  I have no idea why it decided to do that. Just when `Main` needs the lib too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note the build has a order: Common-->B-->A-->Main

If **Main** project has an error, it will not stop the **A** and **B** project's build because they has no error.

**Also**, if the bottom project **Common** has an error, when it will break the whole rebuild process, delete `A` and `Main` project output files.

**Also**, when you try tp change the outdir of the four projects, you should right-click on every project **Properties**-->**General**-->**Output Directories** or just modify every outdir properties of `vcxproj` files. When you rebuild it, it will delete the old location output files and then build again.

In my side, when I run `msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:clean`, it remove the all old previous output files.

If not, I think there are some problems of your current projects. Please try the following steps:

**1)** remove any project references of these projects and then right-click on the **Reference** of related projects-->Re-add project Reference

**2)** re-modify the `outdir` property under each vcxproj files and then make the value the same.

**3)** delete `.vs` hidden folder and any output folders of these four projects.

**4)** Instead, run `msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:rebuild` to build your solution.

**Besides**, if my answer did not meet your requirements, please make your issue more clear and use more pics,.... to describe your issue in more detail.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for spending time with this - I'll try the steps you suggested.  To clarify, all 4 projects compile without errors; the only error I got is the `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file` for the `Common.lib` that got deleted halfway though the build.

Comment: This works! More specifically, re-adding all the project references fixed it (I tested on a clean checkout).  It removed a line `<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>` in the `<ProjectReference>` section of the 2 vcxproj files that depend on `Common`; that fixed the build. Thanks!